# loading cross-domain resources: PHP vs JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, cross-domain

In PHP, there’s the nifty `loadHTMLFile` function.
With it, a script run local fetches any external resources just fine.
Of course it does, since it’s just downloading a file, browser-like, non-interactive.

When I try a JavaScript implementation, `jQuery.get()`, for instance, will nag about cross-domain boundaries.
Of course it does, it respects the same-origin policy.

I’m not sure why this is so.
True, I want to `GET` a specific resource to examine its contents experimentally.
But I don’t want to access its actual live DOM, let alone manipulate it.
I just want the plain text of the HTML file the remote server responds to my request.

1. What’s the fundamental distinction? Are these use cases incomparable?
2. Can JavaScript get (i.e. download) the static contents of an external resource (w/o CORS or other server-side mechanisms)?

Comment: See http://security.stackexchange.com/a/8269. In essence, the fundamental difference is that the Browser issues the requests *on behalf of the browsing user* (typically using cookies), that's effectively letting JavaScript manipulate the user's account on another websites.

Comment: While I find “issued on user’s behalf” helpfully expressed, I still don’t see the security considerations as sole grounds for this particular restriction. Why can’t JS not read the response text
the server would issue any request that is not authenticated? The “logged out version” of the online banking example, if you will. That’s not manipulating at all, but retrieving text, just like `loadHTMLFile` does or a cleared browser would on its first visit.